# Showing text over a TableView when scrolling tableView reaches a threshold

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a label I want to show over a tableview only when the table Reaches a certain threshold while scrolling. The label currently shows but unfortunately does not hide when that the scrolling is below the threshold.

An example of this is how the Clear App shows the "Pull to Clear" label as shown in the image.

Here is the my code attempt. Maybe I'm not hiding the label Appropriately. Not sure. Thanks for the help

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {


        let swipeFurther = UILabel()
        swipeFurther.frame = CGRectMake(10.0, 33.0, 300.0, 20.0)
        swipeFurther.text = "Swipe Further to open the settings."
        swipeFurther.textAlignment = .Left
        swipeFurther.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        swipeFurther.font = UIFont(name: "SF UI Text Regular", size: 9)
        self.view.insertSubview(swipeFurther, aboveSubview: self.tableView)

       swipeFurther.hidden = true    

   if (tableView.contentOffset.y < -(80.0)) {

           swipeFurther.hidden = false

   } 

}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code creates a new `UILabel` every time user scrolls and hides only the newest one if the condition is met. So try something like this;

```
let swipeFurther = UILabel()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    swipeFurther.frame = CGRectMake(10.0, 33.0, 300.0, 20.0)
    swipeFurther.text = "Swipe Further to open the settings."
    swipeFurther.textAlignment = .Left
    swipeFurther.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    swipeFurther.font = UIFont(name: "SF UI Text Regular", size: 9)
    self.view.insertSubview(swipeFurther, aboveSubview: self.tableView)
}

func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if (tableView.contentOffset.y < -(80.0)) {
        swipeFurther.hidden = false
    } else {
        swipeFurther.hidden = true
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Worked Perfectly. :)